# Confusion about Java conversion of bytes to String for comparison of "byte order marks"

Tags: java, utf-8

I'm trying to recognize a BOM for UTF-8 when reading a file. Of course, Java files like to deal with 16 bit chars, and the BOM characters are eight bit bytes.

My test code looks like:

```
public void testByteOrderMarks() {
    System.out.println("test byte order marks");

    byte[] bytes = {(byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xBF, (byte) 'a', (byte) 'b',(byte) 'c'};
    String test = new String(bytes,  Charset.availableCharsets().get("UTF-8"));
    System.out.printf("test len: %s  value %s\n", test.length(), test);
    String three = test.substring(0,3);
    System.out.printf("len %d  >%s<\n", three.length(), three);
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length();i++) {
        byte b = bytes[i];
        char c = test.charAt(i);
        System.out.printf("b: %s %x c: %s %x\n", (char) b, b,  c, (int) c); 
    }
}
```

and the result is:

> test byte order marks
>   test len: 4  value ?abc
>   len 3  >?ab<
>   b: ? ef> c: ? feff
>   b: ? bb c: a 61
>   b: ? bf c: b 62
>   b: a 61 c: c 63

I can't figure out why the length of "test" is 4 and not 6.
I can't figure out why I don't pick up each 8 bit byte to do the comparison.

Thanks

Comment: One question: why do you need to figure out BOM? All decent XML and JSON parsers deal with this, so it is often handled automatically. But maybe your use case is different?

Comment: I'm not reading XML or JSON. Its plain text file from a Windows machine. Somewhere in the workflow they get added, sometimes. So I need to detect them so I can ignore them. I'd rather just ignore them completely, but I can't figure out how to do that either.

Comment: Stop dealing with bytes.  Deal with characters.  BTW, a BOM is not suppose to occur in UTF-8, because it really screws it up.  This is a Microsoft bug.

Comment: @tchrist: It is also a Java bug in Scanner, see http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4508058

Comment: @rossum: No, that is **not a Java bug!** It is a user misunderstanding. A BOM in a UTF-8 stream is not a BOM.  It is data.  The correct way to transcode a 10-char UTF-16 stream (which has a BOM at the front and which *is not counted* in those 10 characters!!)  is to produce a 10-char UTF-8 stream, not an 11-char UTF-8 stream.  Here, write this 10-char Unicode string to a UTF-16 file and transcode it to a UTF-8 file: ``.

Comment: A UTF-16 file holding nothing but the ten Unicode characters "" is 42 bytes long, but the equivalent UTF-8 file also holding those same 10 characters **should be only 40 bytes long, *not* 43 bytes!**  If you screw up the conversion, you get 11 chars in UTF-8 when you had only 10 in UTF-16.  That's a bug.  You cannot expect a UTF-8 reader to deal with UTF-16 bugs. That’s how we got the non-Unicode abomination known as CESU-8: because UTF-16 people keep coding up their misunderstandings of what Unicode really is. That non-bug bug report manifests the same brain-bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A character is a character.  The Byte Order Mark is the Unicode character U+FEFF.  In Java it is the character `'\uFEFF'`.  There is no need to delve into bytes.  Just read the first character of the file, and if it matches `'\uFEFF'` it is the BOM.  If it doesn't match then the file was written without a BOM.

```
private final static char BOM = '\uFEFF';    // Unicode Byte Order Mark
String firstLine = readFirstLineOfFile("filename.txt");
if (firstLine.charAt(0) == BOM) {
    // We have a BOM
} else {
    // No BOM present.
}
```

Comment: @Downvote: what is the problem?  U+FEFF is just another character, "zero-width non-breaking space".  Why the problem with reading a character from a text file?

Comment: -1 This is wrong according to the XML standard (1.1, second edition, see "E.1 Detection Without External Encoding Information" at http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/)

Comment: @Aaron: Your reference gives correct byte sequences, but does not specify that they have to be read as bytes.  The BOM can be read as a single character in any UTF encoding, recognised and discarded if not required.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use characters when trying to figure out the BOM header. The BOM header is two or three *bytes*, so you should open an (File)InputStream, read two bytes and process them.

Incidentally, the XML header (`<?xml version=... encoding=...>`) is pure ASCII so it's safe to load that as a byte stream, too (well, unless there is a BOM to indicate that the file is saved with 16bit characters and *not* as UTF-8).

My solution (see [DecentXML's XMLInputStreamReader](http://code.google.com/p/decentxml/source/browse/src/main/java/de/pdark/decentxml/XMLInputStreamReader.java)) is to load the first few bytes of the file and analyze them. That gives me enough information to create a properly decoding `Reader` out of an `InputStream`.

Comment: Wikipedia says its 3 bytes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark
I'm so confused.

Comment: It is 3 bytes for UTF-8, 2 bytes for UTF-16/UCS-2 -- i.e. it is _one character_, but one character may be any number of bytes, depending on encoding.

Comment: Btw, explanation is correct, this is how other XML and JSON parsers do it; read couple of first bytes, use and skip BOM if any present, if not, determine heuristically from other aspects (both XML and JSON allow this to be reliably detected).

Comment: @fishtoprecords: Check my code; it's not very complex and handles all the corner cases.

Comment: @fishtoprecords: the byte-order *mark* (singular) is a Unicode character, U+FEFF, not a sequence of bytes. It shouldn't appear in UTF-8 encoded text, but if it does, a UTF-8 decoder will output a single character, because that's what it is.

Comment: Aaron, do you do the analysis *only* to determine if a BOM is present in UTF-8 data, *or* to guess the whole encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE)?

Comment: @erickson I looked at aaron's code, and he checks for three bytes. The first two are the big-endian/little-endian flags, but there is a third one, 0xBF.

Comment: @tchrist so please enlighten me on the one truth.

Comment: @fishtoprecords: rossum’s answer is the right one for how to deal with this because it deals with Unicode characters rather than ugly UTF-8 code units. But when you have a BOM in a UTF-8 stream, there is always a bug in the upstream encoder or transcoder, because BOMs have no business being in UTF-8 — ever. They are noncharacters whose presence in a data stream indicates that something was done incorrectly. This even happens with UTF-16 and UTF-32. For example, the file is in UTF-16 but some numbskull used the UTF-16BE decoder on it. That again gives you a bogus noncharacter at the start.

Comment: @tchrist: I understand why you say that but the XML standard is pretty specific about this and my code complies to the standard. See "E.1 Detection Without External Encoding Information" at http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/

Comment: @tchrist You are wrong wrt UTF-8; while there is no real need for it, it can be added and is used. As such it better be dealt with, and in many cases the proper way is to do it before character decoding. XML and JSON are not the only cases, but for both byte-based handling must be done prior to handling content as characters. XML specification does indeed outline a way to handle fairly well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to recognize a BOM file a better solution (and works for me) will be use the encoding detector library of Mozilla: http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/
In that link is described easily how to use it:

```
import org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector;

public class TestDetector {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    String fileName = "testFile.";
    java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(fileName);

    // (1)
    UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null);

    // (2)
    int nread;
    while ((nread = fis.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
      detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread);
    }
    // (3)
    detector.dataEnd();

    // (4)
    String encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset();
    if (encoding != null) {
      System.out.println("Detected encoding = " + encoding);
    } else {
      System.out.println("No encoding detected.");
    }

    // (5)
    detector.reset();
  }
}
```

If you are using maven the dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.juniversalchardet</groupId>
    <artifactId>juniversalchardet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```